# Mockito Matcher for Integer... parameter

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

What's the proper Mockito matcher for the second parameter in this method Signature:

```
List<Something> findSomething(Object o, Integer... ids);
```

I tried the following matchers:

```
when(findSomething(any(), anyInt())).thenReturn(listOfSomething);
when(findSomething(any(), any())).thenReturn(listOfSomething);
```

but Mockito is not creating the proxy for me, the returned `List` is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `anyVararg()` like this:

```
Application application = mock(Application.class);
List<Application> aps = Collections.singletonList(new Application());

when(application.findSomething(any(), anyVararg())).thenReturn(aps);

System.out.println(application.findSomething("foo").size());
System.out.println(application.findSomething("bar", 17).size());
System.out.println(application.findSomething(new Object(), 17, 18, 19, 20).size());
```

**Output:**

```
1
1
1
```

Answer (score 2):

`Integer...` is a syntactic sugar on top of defining an array of `Integer`s. So the correct way to mock it would be:

```
when(findSomething(any(), any(Integer[].class))).thenReturn(listOfSomething);
```

Comment: This is causing a compiler Error: 

    The method findSomething(Object, Integer...) in the type SomethingService is not applicable for the arguments (Object, Matcher<Integer[]>)